# Parse SpreadsheetML using Java

Tags: java, xml, parsing, import-from-excel, spreadsheetml

Need to parse Excel 2003 XML file

```
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" 
  xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" 
  xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" 
  xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" 
  xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
```

File is not zipped as xslt, it is one file xml. So when trying to parse it with Apache POI getting `error in opening zip file` exception.

What is the best way to parse such kind of SpreadsheetML file?

Comment: Have you tried http://xelem.sourceforge.net/